# BID and Valid IP of network 155.44.200.0?

Tags: ip

Q ) Given a class B network of **155.44.200.0**, what mask could be used to provide **15 networks** each supporting **120 users**.
My Understanding :

120 users would require 7 bits of host address space
7 bits of host = 25 bits of network

```
  155.44.200.0    
  155.44.200.128   
  155.44.201.0    
  155.44.201.128  
  155.44.202.0    
     .......
```

with a network mask of    255.255.255.128

Here I am not getting , where this network will end ? because here Subnet Number is 9 bit. So subnetwork will be 512 of each 127 users.
so **155**. **40**. **1100 1000** . **_? | _ _ _ _ _ _ _** ( Host bit 7 ) How that 25th bit will be used in network.
I am confused while explaining but I simply need BID and some Valid IP address of the network. ( specially last valid IP in which 25th bit is used )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really understand the

> so 155. 40. 1100 1000 . _? | _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ( Host bit 7 ) How that 25th bit will be used in network.

part, but i think you did the calculation correctly. You can't have **exactly** 15 subnets with 120 users if that's the part that is confusing to you, so the question should probably be rephrased so it states *at least* 15 subnets.

You begin with the IP from Class B address with a mask:

```
NNNNNNNN.NNNNNNNN.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx
```

You correctly calculated that you need 7 bits for 120 hosts

```
NNNNNNNN.NNNNNNNN.ssssssss.shhhhhhh
```

And you are left with 9 bits for subnets which gives you 512 subnet so the 15 subnets requirement is also met and your /25 mask (255.255.255.128) is a correct answer.

In real situations, of course, you wouldn't need all 512 subnets and you will have for example 155.40.200.0/21 subnet that you will split into 16x /25 subnets — 4 bits for subnets (16) and 7 bits for hosts (128). And since you have multiple subnets you don't have a single broadcast or network ID.

Comment: @ pajaja : I got it that , there wont be single BID. Forget the question. I want to list all subnet.( not exactly list but just to understand )  Means there are 512 subnet namely  155.44. **200.0**  , 155.44. **200.128** , 155.44. **201.0** , 155.44. **201.128**  etc. And I can write only upto 155.4.** 255 **.128. These are hardly ,( 155.44.**200.0** to 155.44. **255.128** ) Theses are not 512 subnet. So where are remaining subnet ?? And in this I have not used last octet's 1st bit ( 25th bit ) which is also a subnet bit. **I want few last subnet of this subnet division.**

Comment: Oh that. If you're looking at all 512 subnets you are not starting from 155.44.200.0 but from 155.44.0.0 because class B network has /16 mask. So your 512 subnets would start from 155.44.0.0, 155.44.0.128 ... and end with 155.44.255.0, 155.44.255.128.

Comment: Referring to above problem , if I want to assign 15 subnetworks to some users , then I must start from 155.44.200.0  ownwards because in example network address has mentioned as 155.44.200.0. Is it correct ??

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The first subnet would be 155.44.200.0/25.